# Seemingly inconsistent column reference syntax when chaining methods on pandas data frames

Tags: python, r, pandas, dplyr

I am a little confused as to why the syntax for referring to a column within a pandas data frame differs depending on which method is being called. Take the following sample method chain

```py
import pandas as pd

iris = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/iris.csv')
iris.columns = ['SepalLength', 'SepalWidth', 'PetalLength', 'PetalWidth', 'Species']
(iris
    .loc[:, ['SepalLength', 'PetalWidth', 'Species']]
    .where(iris['SepalLength'] > 4.6)
    .assign(PetalWidthx2 = lambda x_iris: x_iris['PetalWidth'] * 2)
    .groupby('Species')
    .agg({'SepalLength': 'mean', 'PetalWidthx2': 'std'}))
```

Here, there are three different kinds of syntax used to refer to columns within the iris data frame:

- `loc`, `groupby`, and `agg` all understand that a string refers to a column in the data frame.
- `where` needs the data frame to be explicitly referenced.
- Explicitly referring to the data frame in the `assign` method would cause the operation to be performed on the original iris data frame, and not the copy that has been modified by the calls to `loc` and `where`. Here, `lambda` is needed to refer to the current state of the modified data frame copy.
- In addition to the above, there is also `query`, which takes the entire method input as a string: `iris.query('SepalLength > 4.6')`, but here the pandas documentation explicilty states that this is for special use cases:

  > A use case for query() is when you have a collection of DataFrame objects that have a subset of column names (or index levels/names) in common. You can pass the same query to both frames without having to specify which frame you’re interested in querying

To provide an example of what I mean by consistent data frame column reference syntax, a comparison could be made to the R-package `dplyr`, where columns in the data frame are referenced with the same syntax for all the piped function calls.

```r
library(dplyr)

# The iris data set is preloaded in R
colnames(iris) = c('SepalLength', 'SepalWidth', 'PetalLength', 'PetalWidth', 'Species')
iris %>% 
    select(SepalLength, PetalWidth, Species) %>% 
    filter(SepalLength > 4.6) %>%  
    mutate(PetalWidth2x = PetalWidth * 2) %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>% 
    summarise(SepalLength = mean(SepalLength), PetalWidth2x = sd(PetalWidth2x))
```

Are there advantages that pandas gains from having these different ways of referring to data frame columns, instead of applying the simplistic syntax used by `loc`, `groupby` and `agg` to all the methods (if so, which are these benefits)? Or is this more of a workaround for some underlying issue with using strings for data frame column names in the `assign` and `where` methods?

Comment: I think the biggest difference between `pandas` and `dplyr` is that `pandas` works within Python's existing syntax rules, which are pretty strict with respect to what unquoted symbols can represent (basically objects in the current scope), whereas because R is so flexible in how you can modify symbol lookups `dplyr` has essentially been able to create a DSL for data transformations.

Comment: @Marius Thanks, just to confirm that I understand: Would it be correct to say that it could be technically possible to design a (nearly) identical syntax to `dplyr` in pandas (or another Python package), but due to the stricter Python syntax rules, this would require jumping through too many hoops under the hood to handle special cases, so in the end the cost would simply be too high for the (in my opinion) slightly clearer syntax? Or do you think that a similar syntax is virtually impossible to achieve in Python?

Comment: Some things would be very hard to achieve due to Python's syntax rules, like in `filter(SepalLength > 4.6)`, I don't think there's really a way to defer the evaluation of `SepalLength > 4.6`, that expression has to be something that can be evaluated immediately by itself. I guess everything could be wrapped in strings like `filter('SepalLength > 4.6')`?  But in general it's not a good fit for how Python syntax works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To quote from [Marius's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1222578/marius) comment:

> I think the biggest difference between pandas and dplyr is that pandas works within Python's existing syntax rules, which are pretty strict with respect to what unquoted symbols can represent (basically objects in the current scope)...

I believe that this correct, so let's expand on it a bit.

---

> `loc`, `groupby`, and `agg` all understand that a string refers to a column in the data frame.

```
.loc[:, ['SepalLength', 'PetalWidth', 'Species']]
.groupby('Species')
.agg({'SepalLength': 'mean', 'PetalWidthx2': 'std'}))
```

In all three cases, a string is a valid entity in that context.  That is, the string alone gives enough information to perform the operation. Unlike...

---

> `where` needs the data frame to be explicitly referenced.

```
.where(iris['SepalLength'] > 4.6)
```

In the case of `where`, Python requires the operator `>` to operate against something.  By selecting a specific data frame column, an object was referenced for that column, and the `__gt__` method will be called against that object.

If instead we wanted the syntax to look like:

```
.where('SepalLength' > 4.6)
```

We would need some way to tell Python what the `>` operator meant in this context. The evaluation happens before being passed to `where`.  The existing language feature for this is to provide our own object, with appropriate methods defined, and this is what the pandas designers did.  The default `>` operation for a string is just not useful is this context.

---

> Explicitly referring to the data frame in the `assign` method would cause the operation to be performed on the original iris data frame, and not the copy that has been modified by the calls to `loc` and `where`. Here, `lambda` is needed to refer to the current state of the modified data frame copy.

```
.assign(PetalWidthx2 = lambda x_iris: x_iris['PetalWidth'] * 2)
```

If `.assign` would have been used as the first method of the data frame, prior to any filtering taking place, we could simply have written this as

```
.assign(PetalWidthx2 = iris['PetalWidth'] * 2)
```

since the variable `iris` already exists and is identical to the data frame we want to operate on.

However, since the previous calls to `.loc` and `.where` changes the dataframe we wish to call `.assign` on, it is no longer identical to the `iris` dataframe and there is no defined variable referencing the modified data frame. As pandas is using Python's existing syntax rules, it can utilize `lambda`, which in this context essentially allows for operations on `self`: the current state of the object which `.assign` is called on. There is [an example of this in the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html?highlight=assign#assigning-new-columns-in-method-chains).

This uses the **kwargs of a method, which allows to specify an arbitrary number of parameters (new column names) and their arguments (the value for the new column). The **kwargs `parameter=argument` pairs are interpreted internally as a dictionary `key:value` pair, as can be seen in [the source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.1/pandas/core/frame.py#L2523-L2601).

---

> In addition to the above, there is also `query`, which takes the entire method input as a string: `iris.query('SepalLength > 4.6')`, but here the pandas documentation explicitly states that this is for special use cases

In the case of `query`, the string passed is an expression that will be compiled and executed by a backend that is generally much faster than executing python code.  It is a special case because the available operations are quite limited, and the setup time for the backend engine is large, so it is really only useful for fairly large data sets.

Comment: Thanks! Some aspects are still a bit unclear to me. For example, why could `where` not take an expression like `'SepalLength' > 4.6`, and before that comparison is evaluated, all strings are checked if they match an existing column name. If they do, the data frame column would be used, otherwise the literal string. Naturally, if a comparison with the literal string of a column name is desired, there would need to be special syntax for that, which might get convoluted. But technically, could the syntax have looked like this, or would it have been impossible due to Python restrictions?

Comment: I do not know that it is impossible, as much as impractical.  If it were possible it would be through changing the default behavior for strings, as there is no way to do this in just the context of the call to `where`.  I will update the post to try and add a bit more clarity...

Comment: Excellent answer. Just a quick note: `.where` takes an arbitrary condition. It could work on the DataFrame/Series it was called on, like query,  but we can pass any other conditions that are not directly relevant to that DataFrame/Series as long as the lengths match.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Stressing that pandas is using an existing Python language feature for `.where` helped me understand the previous comment about pandas being restricted to work with existing Python features. That, together with [rereading the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html?highlight=assign#assigning-new-columns-in-method-chains), helped me understand `.assign` better as well. I added clarifications from my thought process to your answer, hopefully not making it too verbose.

Answer (score 0):

[`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) implements `dplyr` syntax, without confusing the reference:

```py
>>> from datar.all import f, select, filter, mutate, group_by, summarise, mean, sd
[2021-06-24 15:20:02][datar][WARNING] Builtin name "filter" has been overriden by datar.
>>> from datar.datasets import iris
>>> 
>>> iris >> \
...     select(f.Sepal_Length, f.Petal_Width, f.Species) >> \
...     filter(f.Sepal_Length > 4.6) >> \
...     mutate(PetalWidth2x = f.Petal_Width * 2) >> \
...     group_by(f.Species) >> \
...     summarise(SepalLength=mean(f.Sepal_Length), PetalWidth2x=sd(f.PetalWidth2x))
      Species  SepalLength  PetalWidth2x
     <object>    <float64>     <float64>
0      setosa     5.119512      0.224043
1  versicolor     5.936000      0.395505
2   virginica     6.588000      0.549300
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of the [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) package.